# $_GET[id] not working in div id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want make link # with id to div id in one page

```
<a href="#?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="team-detail" data-reveal-id="single-news"></a>
```

but id not working in:

```
 <div id="single-news" class="reveal-modal single-news small" data-reveal>

    <?php
         $member = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM team WHERE id = '$_GET[id]'");
         $m = mysql_fetch_array($member);
    ?>  
    <div class="twelve columns first-column">
        <p class="single-news-content"><?php echo $m[quote]; ?></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: you need `$_GET['id']` the id as a string

Comment: btw $m could be a array rows

Answer (score 1):

`id` is key of global array `GET`, so you need to put single or double quote around it.

**Try this code :**

```
<?php
     $member = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM team WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'");
     $m = mysql_fetch_array($member);
?>  
<div class="twelve columns first-column">
    <p class="single-news-content"><?php echo $m[quote]; ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$id = $_GET['id'];
$member = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM team WHERE id = '$id'");
$m = mysql_fetch_array($member);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing variables through URLs.

And PHP can access those variables in the `$_GET` array.

In your case, you are adding variables after hash `#`.

PHP ignores every `$_GET` variable after `#`.

Therefore, you are not getting `$_GET['id']`

Corrected HTML Code:

```
<a href="?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="team-detail" data-reveal-id="single-news"></a>
```

And corrected PHP code:

`$member = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM team WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "');`

Also, please be careful while accessing array variables.

You are using `$_GET[id]`,

It is best practise to use `$_GET['id']` as in case, PHP does not get any array element with key `id`, it will consider `id` as a constant which is obviously not defined.

This may show/log an error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" id="#<?php echo $id; ?>" class="team-detail" data-reveal-id="single-news">test</a>

<div id="single-news" class="reveal-modal single-news small" data-reveal>

    <?php
$id=$_GET[id];
         $member = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM team WHERE id = ".$id."");
         $m = mysql_fetch_array($member);
    ?>  
    <div class="twelve columns first-column">
        <p class="single-news-content"><?php echo $m[quote]; ?></p>
    </div>
```